# Select one row per index value with max column value

Tags: sql, database, db2, greatest-n-per-group, ibm-midrange

With a table setup with the following fields:

```
SKU, EVENTSTARTDATE, EVENTENDDATE, PRICE, (...etc...)
```

and housing thousands of rows here is example data (dates are YYMMDD, century code excluded):

```
1111111, 101224, 101231, 10.99
1111111, 110208, 110220, 9.99
1111111, 110301, 110331, 8.99
2222222, 101112, 101128, 15.99
2222222, 101201, 110102, 14.99
etc
```

I'd like to have a SELECT statement return one row per SKU with the maximum EVENTSTARTDATE without having a WHERE clause isolating a specific SKU or incomplete subset of SKUs (desired SELECT statement should return one row per SKU for all SKUs). I'd eventually like to add the criteria that start date is less than or equal to current date, and end date is greater than or equal to current date, but I have to start somewhere first.

Example results desired (for now just max date):

```
1111111, 110301, 110331, 8.99
2222222, 101201, 110102, 14.99
etc.
```

Comment: So this is a drive-up, write-my-SQL-for-me window? Otoh, how do you ask a query question...

Comment: It's drive-up in that I don't know quite how to do it and am asking how to do it in a SELECT. But the end implementation will eventually require joins across multiple tables, date range criteria, and other things I will have to implement on my own. This is a starting point. I need to know how to do this in general rather than to have it specifically coded for my exact data, but I find it difficult to get across exactly what I'm looking for without providing example data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From recent versions of DB2, you can use the analytical function ROW_NUMBER()

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        tablename.*, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sku 
                           ORDER BY eventstartdate DESC) As RowNum
        FROM tablename) X 
WHERE X.RowNum=1
```

For each Partition (group of SKU), the data is row numbered following the `order by eventstartdate desc`, so 1,2,3,...starting from 1 for the latest EventStartDate.  The WHERE clause then picks up only the latest per SKU.

Comment: @VL20 not sure what you're trying to say here. But RANK() can return multiple rows that have the same eventstartdate, whereas ROW_NUMBER() always returns exactly one row for `rownum = 1`

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I tossed ROW_NUMBER() out as I was having problems getting the syntax to work and wasn't sure if it was supported in the mainframe's version of DB2 [RANK() is supported]. In the case that event start dates are unique within a particular SKU, it shouldn't matter. But ROW_NUMBER is the way to go. Corrected: "SELECT * FROM (SELECT tablename.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sku ORDER BY eventstartdate DESC) As RowNum FROM tablename) X WHERE X.RowNum=1". Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at GROUP BY  and HAVING clauses.

```
select sku, max(eventstartdate)
FROM TABLE
group by sku
having eventstartdate <= sysdate
```

Edit: added HAVING statement

Comment: It has the problem that is not easy to catch the rest of the fiels in the select statement. Don´t forget to put the FROM in the last query.

Comment: Edited: Added the FROM in your last query

Comment: @pcofre FROM definitely helps. Thanks.

Comment: should be a WHERE clause not a HAVING clause....HAVING clause is used if you want to filter on an aggregate....HAVING SUM(AMOUNT) > 10000

Comment: As mentioned by pcofre, it becomes difficult to catch the PRICE associated with an event having max(EVENTSTARTDATE) [for each SKU]. If you add PRICE to the GROUP BY clause then you will get records for every combination of SKU and PRICE, not just the one row per SKU with the max EVENTSTARTDATE [if unique per SKU]. Thanks for the submission though.

Answer (score 0):

other solution

```
 select distinct f3.* 
 from  yourtable f1
 inner join lateral
       (
        select * from yourtable f2
        where f1.SKU=f2.SKU
        order by EVENTSTARTDATE desc, EVENTENDDATE desc
        fetch first rows only
        ) f3 on 1=1
```