# Retrieving other columns when using MAX

Tags: sql, database, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table called `CEV_CLM_EV` that holds statuses of events. I want to try to pull the `MAX` event, but I want to use `CEV_TYPE` elsewhere in my query. Here is the query that pulls everything:

```
SELECT
        CEV_CLM_ID,
        CEV_TYPE,
        CEV_ADD_TS
FROM
        CEV_CLM_EV
WHERE 
        CEV_CLM_ID = 403083306;
```

Results:

```
CEV_CLM_ID  CEV_TYPE CEV_ADD_TS                
----------- -------- --------------------------
  403083306 O        2015-03-11-10.03.51.412566
  403083306 O        2015-03-11-10.04.27.102384
  403083306 DN       2015-03-11-10.04.27.733790
```

If I were to `MAX(CEV_ADD_TS)`, I would need to group by just the `CEV_CLM_ID` which is not valid. But if I group by `CEV_CLM_ID` AND `CEV_TYPE`, I would get duplicates like:

```
SELECT
        CEV_CLM_ID,
        CEV_TYPE,
        MAX(CEV_ADD_TS)
FROM
        CEV_CLM_EV
WHERE 
        CEV_CLM_ID = 403083306
GROUP BY
        CEV_CLM_ID,
        CEV_TYPE
```

Results:

```
CEV_CLM_ID  CEV_TYPE 3                         
----------- -------- --------------------------
  403083306 DN       2015-03-11-10.04.27.733790
  403083306 O        2015-03-11-10.04.27.102384
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select one row per index value with max column value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937046/select-one-row-per-index-value-with-max-column-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I'm reading that right, you want the max datetime for a particular cev_clm_id, and get the associated cev_type that matches the max datetime?

If so, then you can't do it with a simple query:

```
SELECT *
FROM CEV_CLM_EV AS source
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT CEV_CLM_ID, MAX(CEV_ADD_TS) AS timestamp
    FROM CEV_CLM_EV
    GROUP BY CEV_CLM_ID
) AS maxes ON
        (source.CEV_CLM_ID = maxes.CEV_CLM_ID )
    AND (source.CEV_ADD_TD = maxes.timestamp)
```

The subquery gets the max timestamp and its associated ID, then the outer query joins against that timestamp and id to fetch the rest of the associated data.