# Select the most current record per combination of values in fields

Tags: sql, db2, greatest-n-per-group

Query objective:
I'm trying to select a total of 80 records (20 states - 4 records each). Each state has ~20000 records. Ideally, I would like to select only the most current (using ACTIVITY_TSP) record for each of the 4 combinations of Activity Type and Producer Type Code.

Ex.

```
STATE| ACTIVITY_TYPE | PRODUCER_TYPE_CD | ...
-------------------------------------------------------
MI   |     1         |  '01'            | ...
MI   |     1         |  '02'            | ...
MI   |     2         |  '01'            | ...
MI   |     2         |  '02'            | ...
```

Table 1:

```
AGENT_KEY
STATE
ACTIVITY_TYPE
...
ACTIVITY_TSP
```

Table 2:

```
AGENT_KEY
PRODUCER_TYPE_CD
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select one row per index value with max column value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937046/select-one-row-per-index-value-with-max-column-value)

Comment: What is the expected result for the given example?

Comment: Apologies, the example is the expected result for 1 of the 20 states.

Answer (score 0):

A `JOIN` with `GROUP BY`?

```
select STATE, ACTIVITY_TYPE, PRODUCER_TYPE_CD, MAX(ACTIVITY_TSP)
from table1 t1
  join table2 t2 on t1.AGENT_KEY = t2.AGENT_KEY
group by STATE, ACTIVITY_TYPE, PRODUCER_TYPE_CD
```

Or perhaps you want all table1 and table2 columns?

```
select *
from table1 t1
  join table2 t2 on t1.AGENT_KEY = t2.AGENT_KEY
where not exists (select 1 from table1 t1b
                  where t1b.STATE = t1.STATE
                    and t1b.ACTIVITY_TYPE = t1.ACTIVITY_TYPE
                    and t1b.PRODUCER_TYPE_CD = t1.PRODUCER_TYPE_CD
                    and t1b.ACTIVITY_TSP > t1.ACTIVITY_TSP)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t1.*, t2.producer_type_cd,
             row_number() over (partition by t1.state, t1.activity_type, t2.PRODUCER_TYPE_CD
                                order by t1.ACTIVITY_TSP desc) as seqnum
      from table1 t1 join
           table2 t2
           on t1.agent_key = t2.agent_key
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```