# Suggestion of a simple SQL query

Tags: sql, db2

I have the following table:

```
state       product_a          product_b          final_score
FL          Apple              Açai Berries       9
FL          Apricot            Banana             15
FL          Avocado            Coconut            5
FL          Bilberry           Apricot            17
FL          Blackcurrant       Apricot            6
FL          Blackcurrant       Boysenberry        12
FL          Blueberry          Avocado            11
FL          Blueberry          Cantaloupe         6
FL          Cantaloupe         Coconut            1
FL          Currant            Blackcurrant       5
FL          Cherry             Currant            10
FL          Cherimoya          Cherry             6
FL          Cherimoya          Date               14
FL          Cloudberry         Blueberry          16
FL          Coconut            Apricot            14
FL          Cranberry          Damson             1
FL          Date               Banana             5
NY          Apricot            Blackcurrant       5
NY          Apricot            Dragonfruit        15
NY          Avocado            Cherimoya          16
NY          Avocado            Coconut            18
NY          Banana             Damson             14
NY          Bilberry           Apricot            16
NY          Bilberry           Avocado            1
NY          Blackberry         Blackcurrant       20
NY          Blackberry         Cherimoya          12
NY          Blackcurrant       Damson             19
```

Based on "state" and "product_A" I need to return "product_B" with the highest "final_score".
For instance, if I check for NY "state", "product_A" Blackberry, I want my query to return Blackcurrant.

For instance, I used the following query:

```
select product_b from PRODUCTSUGGESTION a,
       (select max(final_score) maxscore from PRODUCTSUGGESTION
       where product_A like '%Blackcurrant%' and state like 'FL') r                   
where r.maxscore=final_score and product_A like '%Blackcurrant%' and state like 'FL'
```

The output would be: Boysenberry

The query I presented above gives me the wanted output. However, I know that joins increase the query complexity. Could anyone suggest another way of doing it with a simpler query?

Comment: please tag RDBMS Name MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server?

Comment: No, there is not other way. If you are worry about perfomace, use `=` instead of `like` and set index on the fields `state` and `product_a`. Joins increase complexity but db are made to handle that query very easy.

Comment: This is known as a [greatest-n-per-group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937046/select-one-row-per-index-value-with-max-column-value) problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like this is too simple to me, but here you go:

```
SELECT product_b FROM PRODUCTSUGGESTION
WHERE state = 'FL' AND product_a = 'Blackcurrant'
ORDER by final_score DESC FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
```

Comment: well done. we were trying to calculate all `product_b` and didnt realize how the dimension change after you apply filter.

Answer (score 0):

You need calculate the maxScore first. Then join both tables to get the name.

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dd9fe/3)**
This use `sql server` cte, `MySql` need inner select instead.

```
WITH maxScore as (
  SELECT state, product_a, max(final_score) as final_score
  FROM Table1
  GROUP BY state, product_a
)
SELECT t.*, m.final_score
FROM Table1 t
inner join maxScore m
   on t.state = m.state
   and t.product_a = m.product_a
   and t.final_score = m.final_score
```

Comment: it seems we still need to join tables. It is not so different from the query I've proposed. I would like to make it one simple query, if possible.

Comment: Depend on your rdbms. On recent version of `mySql` you can do Max(product_b). But only there and is not very `ansi sql`