# SQL - Removing duplicates

Tags: sql, db2

Although not technically a duplicate is there a way to remove results that only have 1 column different?  Want to keep the highest percentage row.

Database: DB2

Anyway I can remove a duplicate that may result like this?:

```
ID| NAME | VALUE
1 | Test | 0.3455%
1 | Test2 | 0.435%
5 | Test | 0.3455%
5 | Test2 | 0.435%
```

Sample data:

```
ID |       NAME       |  VALUE
42 | Water Fill Level | 0.78345%
42 | Valve Fill Level | 0.8546%
65 | Water Fill Level | 0.8934%
65 | Valve Fill Level | 0.93564%
```

Comment: What's the expected result? The lowest percentage? The highest? An average? Something else?

Comment: Do you want to delete both entries?

Comment: I want to keep only the one with the highest percentage.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select one row per index value with max column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937046/select-one-row-per-index-value-with-max-column-value)

Comment: I added sample data to better explain what I'm typing to find the highest percentage of.  I would like to keep the highest percentage of the row with the highest percent.

Answer (score 1):

If you have additional columns, you might want:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by id, column1 order by column2 desc) as seqnum
     from t
    ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, column1, max(column2) 
from table
group by id, column1
```

This query gets max percentage for each id, column1. A new table can be created using this query and then this table can be renamed to original table to get desired result.

Comment: I think the OP is asking about deletion and also can you please provide some context as to why your answer works?

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is not technically certain.
Suppose you have

[image]

Now it's absolutely uncertain what the outcome should be (there are 3 possibilities when you have 3 columns). Try to be more comprehensive in your approach. And edit your question according to what you want specifically.

Answer (score 0):

To delete the rows you don't want, this is the simplest method

```
DELETE FROM
(   SELECT T.*
    ,      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, NAME ORDER BY VALUE DESC) AS SEQNUM
    FROM T
)
WHERE SEQNUM > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Are your value columns correctly evaluating with comparative operators?  If so, this should work:

```
delete from mytable a where value < 
(select max(value) from mytable b where a.id = b.id and a.name = b.name)
```

If there are still duplicates because of identical values in the "value" column, then you can remove the rest with:

```
delete from mytable a where rrn(a) < 
(select max(rrn(b)) from mytable b where a.id = b.id and a.name = b.name and a.value = b.value)
```

If the comparison operator doesn't behave appropriately (change the above queries from deletes into selects in order to check, and you should check!!) then you may need to do some trickery to get it to work.  regexp_replace() and cast would be the direction I would head.  If I misunderstood you and you want to remove all smaller percentages with the same id OR the same name, then change the 'and' to 'or' in the query:

```
delete from mytable a where value < 
(select max(value) from mytable b where a.id = b.id or a.name = b.name)
```